# UITabBar unselected icon tint

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I am trying to change the color of my tab bar icons when the tabs are UNselected. Right now the color is default grey and I can change the color to whatever color I want for when it IS selected.

Apple's dev library said to change the image rendering to "original" instead of its default mode "template." I did that. then it says to use `initWithTitle:image:selectedImage:` I tried to do that as well but I think that's where I messed up. I wrote this in my viewcontroller.m file. What's wrong here?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIImage *stat = [UIImage imageNamed:@"white_stats.png"];
    stat = [stat imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

    (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)nil image:(UIImage *)stat selectedImage:(UIImage *)stat;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same `UIImage` with `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` in both places.

Your code should look something like

```
 UIImage *stat = [UIImage imageNamed:@"white_stats.png"];
 UIImage *statAlwaysOriginal = [stat imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
 self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil image:statAlwaysOriginal selectedImage:stat];
```

The other thing is that there are some actual syntax errors in your post (in the UITabBarItem initialization, but I suspect you just pasted it incorrectly.

Comment: Yes lets say i merely "pasted it incorrectly" haha. I'm actually quite inexperienced in objective c.  Thanks for the correct code Dima. However, my tab bar icon image(white_stats.png) is still grey when its unselected.  The icon image is white on the png file.  I thought this code would render the image as white.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh oops, I switched the image parameters. See the updated code.